# Ionic 4 ion-slide containing ion-cards - layout issue

Tags: ionic4

I'm trying to get slides working where each slide has a number of cards in it.

I've created a stackblitz to show my problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ion-slides-info-zgej2j

Normally, the cards are stacked vertically, and within each card, the header is above the content.

But doing this inside slides shifts the cards, headers, and content into horizontal rows. See Stackblitz for the example.

Any thoughts?

Regards,
Andy

Comment: I've also noticed if I used DIV tags  instead of ion-cards, the same things happen.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I've resolved it. All the content inside the ion-slide must be wrapped by one element, not multiple elements at the same level.

So basically, have multiple ion-cards, and insert them into one div:

```
<ion-slide>
    <div>
        <ion-card />
        <ion-card />
        <ion-card />
    </div>
</ion-slide>
```